# Unable to discover BLE Device

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE device. Device has one button. Target is to trigger certain action in android device when device button is pressed.

My issue is, i am able to discover and pair with my BLE device via system bluetooth scanner. But when i use, BLE Scanning inside code(same as google code), i am unable to see device.

**I have my Following tags in my manifest.**

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
```

**This is my gradle setup**

```
minSdkVersion 18, targetSdkVersion 22

Phone- Nexus 5 | Android M
```

Here are logs. As you can see in bold text, it discovers device, but doesnt add it. **Any idea why this is happening?**

```
BtGatt.GattService﹕ registerClient() - UUID=b7516aaa-22b1-4d8f-a71e-405e5584edcf BtGatt.GattService﹕ onClientRegistered() - UUID=b7516aaa-22b1-4d8f-a71e-405e5584edcf, clientIf=5

BtGatt.GattService﹕ start scan with filters

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ handling starting scan

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=2 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams - scanInterval = 8000configureRegularScanParams - scanWindow = 8000

BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanParamSetupCompleted : 0

bt_btif_gattc﹕ btif_gattc_update_properties BLE device name=Security Tag len=12 dev_type=2 bt_btif_gattc﹕ btif_gattc_update_properties BLE device name=BlueFind len=15 dev_type=2

BtGatt.GattService﹕ stopScan() - queue size =1

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ stop scan

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped

BtGatt.GattService﹕ unregisterClient() - clientIf=5

BtGatt.GattService﹕ registerClient() -
**UUID=2f2450e9-ea7a-4dfe-aef2-27bcd75c83c5**

BtGatt.GattService﹕ onClientRegistered() - UUID=2f2450e9-ea7a-4dfe-aef2-27bcd75c83c5, clientIf=5

BtGatt.GattService﹕ start scan with filters

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ handling starting scan BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - queue=1

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=2 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=-2147483648

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams - scanInterval = 8000configureRegularScanParams - scanWindow = 8000

BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanParamSetupCompleted : 0

**bt_btif_gattc﹕ btif_gattc_update_properties BLE device name=Security Tag len=12 dev_type=2**
**bt_btif_gattc﹕ btif_gattc_update_properties BLE device name=BlueFind len=15 dev_type=2**

BtGatt.GattService﹕ stopScan() - queue size =1

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ stop scan

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - queue=0

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - ScanSetting Scan mode=-2147483648 mLastConfiguredScanSetting=2

BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ configureRegularScanParams() - queue emtpy, scan stopped

BtGatt.GattService﹕ unregisterClient() - clientIf=5
```

**--EDIT1--**

Here is my code snippet

```
   private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

// Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        mInflator = BLEScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
            mLeDevices.add(device);
        }
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        final BluetoothDevice  device = mLeDevices.get(i);
        final String deviceName = device.getName();
        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
        else
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
        return view;
    }
}

// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Comment: Try not to pair the device and check

Comment: Can you post the code snippet you're using?

Comment: Hi @somesh
Pretty much standard code. I have mentioned it.

Comment: @Materazzi06 I have tried it. Used multiple phones as well, no success.

Comment: i'm having similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060622/android-ble-startdiscovery-callback-is-not-fired-even-with-location-permission. I've noted you're using old (pre-21 BLE API to discover device). I've tried new API (using getLeScanner()) and it still not works for me. Were you able to solve it? Also i can see in your log some devices were found but callback not fired. Is it correct?

Comment: @Vegito1044 i am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution ?.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use a BluetoothAdapter to display your device or do you use a BluetoothGattCallback in a Service ?

Do the UUID in bold correspond to your device's service UUID ?

Comment: Yup that is my device. PFA code snippet. i am using Adapter to display

Comment: Is your adapter set to your ListView ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have location settings on?  Android 6.0+ requires location settings.  You should add to you manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Once this is done you must go into your phone settings and manually enable location permissions.  This is done through **Settings>Privacy and Safety>App Permissions**

Don't ask my why Bluetooth needs location permissions.  It doesn't make sense to me either.  In fact, it still needs location settings even if the location function is turned off.